# Authenticated users with both Android and web (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I try to sync data for a Cognito authenticated user using the new User Pool.

From what's suggested [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js):
"Note that the generate client secret box must be unchecked because the JavaScript SDK doesn't support apps that have a client secret."

On the other hand for Android only apps with a client secret are supported.

So I added 2 apps to the User Pool, one with a client secret and one without it.

However, in the Identity Pool I can only add one App Client ID as an authentication provider.

So I get: "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool." when trying to use an authenticated token for the Android app.

Am I doing it right, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
It is possible to add multiple (up to 100) apps or "audiences" to an OIDC provider through the IAM as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html)

So I set up the OIDC and added it as the authentication provider to the identity pool.

Comment: A developer from Cognito here. Currently Cognito supports multiple app client id but console does not reflect it. The fix for this is in our backlog and will be coming soon. Meanwhile one option is to use the CLI to update your pool,  and you should continue to use CLI to update your pool untill the fix is deployed. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/update-identity-pool.html
And yes, it is possible to integrate user pools as an OIDC provider as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already worked out a solution, one additional thought:

> On the other hand for Android only apps with a client secret are supported.

The Android SDK for Cognito User Pools should allow you to handle apps without a secret, you should be able to just set that value to null. Check out the [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo) for more details, if you are interested.

Comment: That's not the issue at all.

Comment: Edited answer to make that more clear. I wasn't trying to answer the original question as you already found a solution, but to point an incorrect part of it for the sake of future readers who may find this.